# Mega drop-downs in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I've read an [interesting article](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/mega-dropdown-menus.html) on mega drop-down usability. The article contains screenshots of what I'm trying to achieve in Flex.

What is the best way to implement mega drop-downs in Flex?
Or maybe someone has already created reusable components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember answering a similar question here :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185128/how-can-i-create-menu-like-this-in-flex-3/3185300#3185300